# Responsive text box with GeometryReader

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create responsive changes to some view parameters (e.g. font size, container box size) based on how much of a given space a text element is occupying at a given moment. The text must also be pushed to the right side of the space, which I'm accomplishing by grouping it with a Spacer() inside an HStack. Because of the space-greediness (and a related behavior I don't understand) of GeometryReader, I'm having a hard time getting the sizing variables I need without breaking the intended structure and behavior of the view.

Here's a version of the view *without* the responsive changes. The text appears where it should within the rounded rectangle:

```
struct responsiveTextBox: View {
    @State var text = "Hi. "
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(text)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            Button("Add text") {
                text += "Hi. "
            }
            Button("Erase text") {
                text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Appearance of view with desired position of text]

In order to implement functionality that responds to the relative amount of space occupied by the text, I need to know the size of either the Spacer() element or the Text() element itself. Wrapping the Spacer() in a GeometryReader doesn't work, because unlike the Spacer alone, the GeometryReader won't shrink to less than 50% of the HStack's width:

```
[...]
HStack {
    GeometryReader() {freeSpace in
        Spacer()
    }
    Text(text)
}
[...]
```

[image: Effect of wrapping Spacer in GeometryReader]

I don't really understand this behavior.

The alternative - wrapping the Text() element in a GeometryReader - also doesn't work, because the GeometryReader's space-greediness overrides the Spacer's, and the text appears on the left side of the rounded rectangle.

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    GeometryReader() {textSpace in
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

[image: Effect of wrapping Text in GeometryReader]

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: can you explain what behavior exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure! I need to experiment some before I'll be sure of the exact design, but basically, when horizontal space available to the Text element is filled (i.e., once the spacer has shrunk to nothing), change the text size and/or adjust the dimensions of the ZStack. Then, when allotted vertical space is used, stop accepting user input. The idea is to use a GeometryReader in combination with an onChange modifier, but perhaps there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these you can use `GeometryReader` in an overlay or background of the element you are interested in – so it does not affect the layout.

IMHO you also don't need the `Spacer` or `HStack`, just set the alignment on `ZStack`.

And ultimately you might want to look into the new `Layout` protocol. It seems to be the way to go for what you want to achieve. [Example here](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/11/16/building-custom-layout-in-swiftui-basics/)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text = "Hi. "
    @State var textSize = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke()
                Text(text)
                    .id(text)
                    .background( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear { textSize = geo.size }})
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            
            Button("Add text") {
                text += "Hi. "
            }
            Button("Erase text") {
                text = ""
            }
            Text("Width: \(textSize.width), Height: \(textSize.height)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets me close, but I need to use onChange, rather than onAppear; the function must run every time the text value changes. What can I apply the onChange view modifier to, if the GeometryReader doesn't itself wrap any view elements?

Comment: how about `.onChange(of: text)`? :)

Comment: "of: text" is fine for that parameter, but doesn't onChange itself, as a view modifier, need to be applied to a view? A GeometryReader placed inside a background modifier contains no views. In your example, "onAppear" is applied to "Color.clear" (i don't totally understand that piece, actually) but I don't think the same works for onChange.

Comment: and of course, the onChange closure needs to be within the scope of the GeometryReader in order to access the GeometryProxy object

Comment: ah I misunderstood your earlier comment. you don't need an `.onChange`, because I added `.id(text)`. This forces the redraw of the view when `text`changes, and in turn again calls the `GeometryReader` :) you can see that working in my demo code. Width and Height are refreshed whenever you add text.

Comment: Ah I see! This is strange though -- your example works on its own, and it works in my app when the text lives in a @State var -- but when the text is in an observed object (my view model), the onAppear closure runs only once, and not with every update of the text. So it seems updates to State are required for the type of redraw that triggers onAppear? Anyway, I appreciate all your help, please do not feel obligated to go all the way down this rabbit hole with me :)

Comment: it should also work with @ObservedObject ... in you "Add Text" Button action try and insert `nameOfyourObservedObject.objectWillChange.send()`

Comment: No luck in my app. The button actions are triggered from within a different view, which might have something to do with it - but the observed object is a single class instance shared between multiple views. This gets tougher as the specifics of my app diverge from the reduced example, unfortunately.